# Where does the phrase 「ノリが悪い」 come from and what is the meaning?

Tags: etymology, definitions

What is this phrase 「ノリが悪い」? I've seen it in a few places, but I haven't been able to find it in a dictionary yet. I had first thought it meant that "the seaweed was bad".

What is the meaning of this phrase and where does it come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have two phrases with this word:

> ノリが悪い人| someone who never joins in
>
> この曲はノリがいい| this song has a good beat

They come from 総まとめ　語彙　N2.

As for origin, I think it might come from expressions close to: 相談に乗る or リズムに乗って踊る (dance to the music)*　which have been adopted in similar fashion to arrive at ウケがいい：

> 若者に受ける映画｜that movie that is very popular among young people =>
>
> ギャグがウケなかった｜the joke did not go down very well =>
>
> ウケがいい｜very popular

(From: 総まとめ　語彙　N1)

But somebody else may have a more firm insight

Note_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_***

*Similar expressions I find easy to remember are:

> 調子に乗っていると 失敗するよ｜You'll fail if you get carried away too much
>
> 経済が回復軌道に乗る| "The economy will gets back on recovery track" (lit: back into orbit)

Comment: Apparently the origin is from Noh theatre, where ノリ is the term used for the counting of the rhythm. If you had good rhythm　`ノリが良い`, if you didn't `ノリが悪い`. Which makes sense, as it basically means you don't fit in with the group, or your our of rhythm with the group.

Comment: Nice! I presume that the ノリ from 能 theatre comes from 乗る, though, as Tim suggested...? Two of the many meanings of 乗る are "to get into the swing" or "to join/participate". Pity we don't have a different 漢字 for these concepts, like we have for 載る...

Answer (score 4):

And don't forget the very useful ノリノリ, which basically means ノリが良い. I was at a club once and one of my American friends named Thomas ran out and started dancing like crazy. My Japanese friend turned to me and said, トマス、ノリノリだね。

Comment: Oops...meant this to be a comment under the answer above, but I'm not sure how to fix it now.

Comment: Ah I've done that too, and someone told me I couldn't post a comment till I got 50 reputations...