# Difference between 付き合いが悪い and ノリが悪い

Tags: translation, meaning, words, expressions

In a manga, a girl is reproaching her friend for not being very sociable since she became friend with a guy from the school cinema club:

> あんた　あの映研のメガネとつるむようになってから**つきあい悪い**し**ノリも悪い**

I read on Kenkyusha dictionary that 付き合いの悪い人 is "an unsociable person", while [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6587/where-does-the-phrase-%E3%83%8E%E3%83%AA%E3%81%8C%E6%82%AA%E3%81%84-come-from-and-what-is-the-meaning) I read that ノリが悪い人 is "someone who never joins in". To me they look pretty similar, but since they are used together in the sentence, there must be a slight difference. Could someone plese explain what this difference is? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ノリ is a slangy term, and it corresponds to the fourth definition [here](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%B9%97%E3%82%8A): "(getting into the) mood; (entering into the) spirit; energy; enthusiasm; rhythm; feeling". So ノリが悪い is more about one's vibes, atmosphere, etc. Simply put, by ノリが悪い, the girl is saying her friend seems bored and not energetic when they are together.

付き合いが悪い is relatively more objective, and mainly refers to the reluctance to be together in their free time. For example, if someone turned down an invitation to go to a movie/izakaya/etc without good reason, that may be 付き合いが悪い.